# How to Return the ID Value When Inserting a Record Using ElevateDB

Tags: sql, delphi, elevatedb

With SQL server you can simply return `@@Identity` to get the `ID` value of the last insert.

Is there a way to do this using [elevatedb](/questions/tagged/elevatedb)?

Comment: Note that it is better to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() with SQL Server most of the time.

Comment: @Linas it's the concept of SELECT @@IDENTITY that I'm interested in mimmicking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ElevateDB provides a [LASTIDENTITY](http://www.elevatesoft.com/manual?action=viewtopic&id=edb2sql&topic=LASTIDENTITY) function which returns the last identity value assigned to the specified column in the specified table.

```
SELECT LASTIDENTITY('Customer', 'CustNo') AS LastCustNo
```

You can also obtain the same information using the INSERT statement.

```
EDBQuery1.SQL.Clear;
EDBQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, Text1)');
EDBQuery1.SQL.Add('VALUES(:ID, :Text1)');
EDBQuery1.Prepare;
EDBQuery1.ParamByName('Text1').AsString:='Some text';
EDBQuery1.ExecSQL;
ShowMessage(EDBQuery1.ParamByName('ID').AsString);
```

> INSERT statements automatically set all parameters to IN/OUT so that
>   any generated/computed column values (including IDENTITY columns) can
>   be retrieved via the same parameters after the INSERT is executed.

The above example is from the [Support Forum](http://www.elevatesoft.com/forums?action=view&category=edb&id=edb_sql&page=1&msg=4220#4220).

Answer (score 0):

ElevateDB does not support identity or auto-incrementing column types. So, there is no syntax like `@@Identity`.

Comment: @stukelly - One of your links points to LASTIDENTITY. Make this an answer and you get my vote.